# JQuery Load Error, $() is not a function, shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery

Perhaps im missing something obvious, im using shopify and I'm calling in jQuery in the head of the theme.liquid file

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Right under the  tag.

Now, I'm trying to call the function within my product.template file:

```
      <script src="{{ 'easyResponsiveTabs.js' | asset_url }}"></script>

      <div id="horizontalTab">
        <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
        <li>Tab 1</li>
        <li>Tab 2</li>
        <li>Tab 3</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="resp-tabs-container">
        <div>
        <p>...</p>
        </div>
        <div>
        <p>...</p>
        </div>
        <div>
        <p>...</p>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#horizontalTab').easyResponsiveTabs({

        // Types: default, vertical, accordion   
        type: 'default', 

        //auto or any width like 600px
        width: 'auto', 

        // 100% fit in a container
        fit: true,

        // Close the panels on start, 
        // the options 'accordion' and 'tabs' keep them closed in there respective view types
        closed: false,

        // The tab groups identifier
        tabidentify: '',

        // background color for active tabs in this group
        activetab_bg: 'white',

        // background color for inactive tabs in this group
        inactive_bg: '#F5F5F5',

        // border color for active tabs heads in this group
        active_border_color: '#c1c1c1',

        // border color for active tabs contect in this group 
        // so that it matches the tab head border
        active_content_border_color: '#c1c1c1',

        activate: function () {}

        });

        });

      </script>


     </div>
```

It's giving me this error in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).easyResponsiveTabs is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (tiger-quick-dry-towel?_sc=1&design_theme_id=80470442073&frame_token=okgdtQLQtOjs4biyW0o3RFFLHDplhpI3PzmLeYxB53bKa3onKoldn96toU9MuQ9szs-U7NX6sE5E_MYWODZQKLGYheUmgwR6D_3VimWz4zOq5bNDXYG6ZMyBgzNe2JphxVM4T7YJXyBvJY3Oe6otlQ%3D%3D&preview_theme_id=:1149)
    at c (jquery-1.9.1.min.js?v=16339757027993502959:3)
```

For some reason the Jquery isn't loading but I can't think of anything else I can do to make it work after trying several different things.

Thanks if you can help.
Dale.

Comment: Error says jQuery is loaded, it is the library is not registered. That usually means you have two versions of jQuery on the page.

Comment: `easyResponsiveTabs` is not a function, jquerys loaded fine

Comment: `easyResponsiveTabs` is not part of "jquery" - it's an additional plugin that you need to include in your page via a `<script>` tag (that must appear after the jquery script tag and before your own script tag)

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, I can't find another jquery verison.  i call in the function with this: '      <script src="{{ 'easyResponsiveTabs.js' | asset_url }}"></script>
' above the function

Comment: Hey @freedomn-m, I do call in the easyResponsiveTabs with the script as shown above!

Comment: You're referring to this `<script src="{{ 'easyResponsiveTabs.js' | asset_url }}"></script>` I assume - given that it's not pure HTML, I suggest you look at what's being rendered (view source in the browser) and check the console / network tabs for errors on that line.   Can you include in your question what this looks like *rendered*?

Comment: I doubt, has `easyResponsiveTabs.js` loaded. Just check in network tab of developer tools in browser.

Comment: Look at the network tab, do you see a 404? When you look at the html inspeact, do you see the correct path?

Comment: the easyResponse file is a 200, the only 404 is is a jquery call on something else!

Comment: Ok, we can only go one what you've provided and make some guesses based on experience of previous questions (such as the first comment above).  The next step is for you to create a [mcve] - a snippet in your question that *demonstrates* the problem - this explains it in detail: [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  Without this, it's unlikely you'll get a resolution.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m, In the end it was two things, jquery was being loaded twice and there was a component missing from the jquery plugin I was using, it wasn't mentioned in the guide. Thanks for your help. Have a great day/evening.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set the dynamic src of js file

```
<script src="{{ 'easyResponsiveTabs.js' | asset_url }}"></script>
```

instead, on document load, you can load the script as below

```
$(function(){
 var scr = document.createElement( 'script' );
  scr.setAttribute('src', asset_url + '\easyResponsiveTabs.js');
  document.body.appendChild(scr);
});
```

Comment: Yeah I dont think thats it mate

Comment: Indeed, he's not using (or specifying using) any `.js` framework (or other js/html template framework). This is a valid presumption.

Comment: OP has shows only jquery reference in the code and there's no other tag for the question to indicate the use of other js framework